# Problem in computing self-induction for a wire with zero diameter

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

This is quoted form Edward Purcell's *Electricity and Magnetism*; it tells about the problem of computing magnetic flux during self-induction for a wire with zero-diameter:

> You may think that one of the rings we considered earlier would have made a simpler example to illustrate the calculation of self-inductance. However, if we try to calculate the inductance of a simple circular loop of wire, we encounter a puzzling difficulty. It seems a good idea to simplify the problem by assuming that the wire has zero diameter. But we soon discover that, if finite current flows in a filament of zero diameter, the flux threading a loop made of such a filament is infinite! The reason is that the field $B$, in the neighbourhood of a filamentary current, varies as $1/r,$ where $r$ is the distance from the filament, and the integral of $B \times \text{area}$ diverges as $\int (dr/r)$ when we extend it down to $r= 0$. To avoid this, we may let the radius of the wire be finite, and not zero, which is more realistic anyway. This may make the calculation a bit more complicated, but that won't worry us. The real difficulty is that different parts of the wire now appear as *different circuits*, linked by different amounts of flux. We are no longer sure what we mean by *the* flux through *the* circuit. In fact, because the electromotive force is different from the different filamentary loops into which the circuit can be divided, some *redistribution*  of current density must occur when rapidly changing currents flow in the ring. Hence the inductance of the circuit may depend somewhat on the rapidity of $I$ ...
>
> We avoided this embarrassment in the toroidal coil example by ignoring the field in the immediate vicinity of the individual turns of the winding. Most of the flux does *not* pass through the wire themselves, and whenever that is the case the effect we have just been worrying about will be unimportant.

Why did he take $r= 0$ in the integral? Did he want to find the flux of the field *on* the wire also? Also, even if he takes a non-zero diameter wire, shouldn't there be magnetic field on the wire then also? How did by taking non-zero diameter wire, problem with $r= 0$ in the integration vanished? Shouldn't there be magnetic field lines passing through the wire even if the wire is having non-zero diameter?

Comment: I would strongly recommend asking small focused questions. When you ask three questions at once, you severely reduce the probability that someone will give a good answer. Think of it like this: suppose the probability that a user can read, understand, think of an answer for, and write an answer for a particular question is $p \ll 1$. If you ask three questions, the probability that someone can answer is $p^3$. If $p \approx 0.01$, then you've now got one chance in a million that someone can answer.

Comment: To be specific, I could probably answer your first question, but not the second two. The first one is a well defined focused question admitted good answers. The second two questions are kind of vague, so I don't want to try to answer them. So now rather than write a useful answer, I do nothing.

Comment: @DanielSank: Really sorry for that. I would remove the second two and probably would make them as a new question. Thanks for those comments.

Comment: @DanielSank: Removed... you can check the question now.

Comment: Nice improvement. I think we can start getting somewhere now. Try this: can you write down the integral for the flux of a long straight wire? Try that, edit it into the post, and let's see where we can go from there. I think we'll see where the $r=0$ is coming from, and we'll also understand why the integral diverges.